# Reports: Exclude blank values from average

Tags: reporting, formula

I'm looking to create a report with a number of opportunities, summarised by 'Meeting Source'. I want to have the average amount of an opportunity per 'Meeting Source' EXCLUDING the ones that don't have an amount yet (or amount = 0).

For example:

A  10
B  15
C  5
D  -

The average should be 10 and not 7.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to handle these type of value natively. Salesforce currently has no support for it.
Here idea has been submitted https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpPYAA0
same as your issue. You have to manually do this by adding filter to generated report.

Comment: @MikeChale Thats something valuable to us if delivered and will save lot of efforts and headache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter out the bad values. Your example,

> A 10 B 15 C 5 D -
>
> The average should be 10 and not 7.5.

would work if you filter where `Meeting Source is not equal to` because the report would then only contain entries for records A, B, and C. Continue in this fashion filtering out all unwanted values.

**Note:** For filtering out blank values you just leave the filter field empty, as shown in the highlighted portion of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this can be to do the following:

1. Create a row-level formula that returns 1 if the "non-blank" condition is met, and 0 if it is not.
   e.g. FieldNotBlank = "if(isblank(fieldname), 0, 1)"
2. Create a summary-formula to get the average of the desired field (say, "Age") using the sum of the "non-blanks", returning zero if the "divisor" is zero to prevent an "error" [divide-by-zero].
   (Here "ABC01" is the field-code Salesforce gave to our FieldNotBlank formula field):-
   e.g. AverageAge = "IF(ABC01:SUM > 0, Person_Age__C:SUM / ABC01:SUM, 0)"

This will get the average but will ignore the ones that did not meet the "non-blank" criteria.